# ASP.NET postbacks creates issue in URL rewriting?

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

I am using Intelligencia for url rewriting in my asp.net project.

I have solved many issues by doing R & D for url rewriting but right now i stuck with one issue regarding page postback.

page postback change my rewrite url to original url.

SO, anyone help me to get out from here.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can code this in your master page for this problem

Here `form1` is the `form` tag and place it in master page's load event

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form1.Action = Request.RawUrl;
    }
```

Comment: It works perfectly for me also upvoted, but i have a question, it might be silly though, is this turning the update responce a little bit slow, it might be a combination with th urlrewrite because from the time i add the rewritte my ypdate panel were failing till now but now they are slow! THanks in advance guys!

Comment: This works great. My site uses a main masterpage with the form tag on it, so just adding this line to masterpage Load event fixed the full site

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to use a custom From control to handle the re-written URLs, there's an excellent blog from Scott Gu on the subject here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx

It should be a good starting point.